# Android build error :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Tags: android

It is log error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpResponse
>   When i build app, it's error with show log same. But when i copy project to different computer, it is run ok.

Comment: Try Cleaning and Rebuilding the project.

Comment: have not working. :(

Comment: Do you have all the proper include statements and compile statements?

Comment: Yes,I copy project. run android 1.5 (no error) run android 2.0 (error) which error same.

Comment: Thank i have fix success. when build different. Add compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"

Comment: Glad to hear this fixed your issue. Normally, when you get a ClassNotFoundException for a file outside of your project, its because you didn't compile it in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix success, add :compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"